# Get index of a class Element

Tags: html, jquery

I've been stuck for hours on a problem that might be actually simple but I can't manage to find the solution.

To be short, I want to know the index (ie the first / the second / the third etc...) of a checkbox when clicking on it.

Here's the jsfiddle showing what's currently working and what is not. I've tried many things but couldn't find the solution I'm looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/cpydwqk3/2/ `<div>`(this example applies only for the class "admin" which applies herself on the checkbox "admin").

```js
function usermodif(identifiant) {
  alert($('.admin').index(this)); //return -1
}


$("tr").click(function() {
  alert($("tr").index(this)); //work but applies on whole line
});
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Utilisateurs</caption>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">pseudo</th>
    <th scope="col">points</th>
    <th scope="col">points_session</th>
    <th scope="col">admin</th>
    <th scope="col">banni</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">firstguy</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="points" value="45" id="points"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="points_session" value="6" id="points_session"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="admin" name="admin" onclick="usermodif(this.className)"> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="banni" name="banni"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Nico</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="points" value="21" id="points"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="points_session" value="21" id="points_session"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="admin" name="admin" onclick="usermodif(this.className)" checked> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="banni" name="banni"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">anonyme</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="points" value="0" id="points"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="points_session" value="0" id="points_session"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="admin" name="admin" onclick="usermodif(this.className)"> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="banni" name="banni"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Traverse first tp the closest TR. Than get that closest TR index.
TR has an index amongst TBODY TRs, but not the checkbox.

Also, never use inline JavaScript `on*` attributes, same as you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes. JS and CSS should be in one place only, and that's their respective files or tags.

```js
$(".admin").on("click", function() {
  const $par = $(this).closest("tr");
  alert($par.index());
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">firstguy</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="points" value="45" id="points"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="points_session" value="6" id="points_session"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="admin" name="admin"> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="banni" name="banni"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">firstguy</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="points" value="45" id="points"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="points_session" value="6" id="points_session"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="admin" name="admin"> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="banni" name="banni"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```